# NVD3 How to remove Y-axis in Line chart and also utilize the space of Y-axis after it is removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, linechart, angular-nvd3

I am using NVD3 for showing a line chart.
I have this line chart as follows:

```
chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 150,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 40,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                "xAxis": {
                    ticks:7,
                    showMaxMin : false,
                    tickFormat: 
                        function (d) { 
                        var x = globalFactory.getCalendarConstants().dateMap.weekDayShortLabels
                        return x[d] },
                },
                showYAxis:false,
                showLegend : false,
            }
```

It removes the `Y-Axis` but the space of `Y-axis` is not Utilized. I want to use up that space.

Is their any solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adjusting the margins (see below), though you may have to play with it a bit to get that spaced out the way you want it.

```
margin : {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 40,
          left: 0
         },
```

Comment: On which element should i try the margin?